# Travel to the USA from India with passport validity of less than 6 months?

Tags: usa, passports, indian-citizens, passport-renewals, air-india

Can I travel to the USA from India with a passport validity of less than 6 months? I have an Indian passport with a validity 10 days short of 6 months, traveling with an Air India flight. Will there be any issue?

Comment: Hi Sujata! Can you confirm if you were able to travel on Air India with less than 6 months passport to US?

Answer (score 6):

> Can I Travel to USA from India with passport validity of less than 6 months?

Yes,

The normal rule is that you need 6 months worth of validity to enter the US, but it doesn't apply to the members of the *6 month club*, which are listed in [9 FAM 403.9-3(B)(2) § f](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html)

> Citizens of the countries listed below are exempt from the six-
> month rule and need only have a passport valid for their intended period of stay

As of September 7th, 2023 :

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andorra | Angola | Antigua and Barbuda |
| Antilles | Argentina | Armenia |
| Aruba | Australia | Austria |
| Bahamas, The | Barbados | Belgium |
| Belize | Bermuda | Bolivia |
| Bosnia-Herzegovina | Brazil | Bulgaria* |
| Burma | Canada | Chile |
| Colombia | Costa Rica | Cote D’Ivoire |
| Croatia* | Cyprus | Czech Republic |
| Denmark | Dominica (DOMN) | Dominican Republic |
| Egypt | El Salvador | Estonia |
| Ethiopia | Federated States of Micronesia | Fiji |
| Finland | France | Gabon |
| Georgia | Germany | Greece |
| Grenada | Guatemala | Guinea |
| Guyana | Haiti | Holy See (Vatican City) |
| Hong Kong | Hungary | Iceland |
| **India** | Indonesia | Ireland |
| Israel | Italy | Jamaica |
| Japan | Kosovo* | Latvia |
| Lebanon | Libya | Liechtenstein |
| Lithuania | Luxembourg | Macau |
| North Macedonia | Madagascar | Malaysia |
| Maldives | Malta | Mauritania |
| Mauritius | Mexico | Monaco |
| Mongolia | Montenegro | Mozambique |
| Nepal | Netherlands | New Zealand |
| Nicaragua | Nigeria (NRA) | Norway |
| Pakistan | Palau | Panama |
| Papua New Guinea (PNG) | Paraguay* | Peru |
| Philippines | Poland | Portugal |
| Qatar | Romania | Russia |
| San Marino | Saudi Arabia* | Serbia |
| Seychelles | Singapore** | Slovakia |
| Slovenia | South Africa | South Korea |
| Spain | Sri Lanka | St. Kitts and Nevis |
| St. Lucia | St. Vincent and The Grenadines | Suriname |
| Sweden | Switzerland | Taiwan |
| Thailand | Trinidad and Tobago | Tunisia |
| Turkey | Tuvalu | Ukraine |
| United Arab Emirates | United Kingdom | Uruguay* |
| Uzbekistan | Venezuela | Zimbabwe |

India being present in that list,  you can enter the US

Comment: As the other answer notes, someone with a passport expiring in less than six months will not be admitted past the expiration date of the passport.  For example, a traveler with a B-2 visa is normally admitted for six months.  Someone arriving with a six-month-club passport that expires in two weeks will be admitted for two weeks.  (Similarly, those with passports from other countries are admitted until six months before their passport expires. So a traveler arriving with a non-six-month-club passport that expires in seven months' time will be admitted for one month.)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to travel and come back with 4 months' validity on my Indian passport and 5 months' validity on my US visa on Air India from Delhi to New York for a 10-day visit without any issue.

I am sharing because I was stuck in this loop of approaching embassies and airline office with no clear answer. Though, for peace of mind it's suggested that you renew your Indian passport, even on urgent (tatkal) quota.

Comment: It's worth noting that the visa validity does not limit the allowed duration of stay.  You can arrive on the visa's expiration date and be admitted for six months.  The passport validity, however, _does_ affect the duration of stay; if you look at the admission stamp (if you have one) it should show an "until" date that is either the same as the passport's expiration date or earlier.

Answer (score 3):

A nonimmigrant is inadmissible under [8 USC 1182(a)(7)(B)(i)(I)](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title8-section1182&num=0&edition=prelim#substructure-location_a_7_B_i_I) unless they have a passport valid until 6 months after the end of their period of admission. What this means in practice is that for people with passports from countries not on the "6-month club", their passport must be valid for at least 6 months at the time of entry, and the admit-until date on their I-94 will be no later than 6 months before their passport expires. For people with passports from countries on the [6-month club](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2), their passport must be valid for any length at the time of entry, and the admit-until date on their I-94 will be no later than their passport expiration date.

Since you are using an Indian passport, and India is in the 6-month club, you can enter the US with a passport of less than 6 months of validity left. However, note that if you are entering on a status with a fixed date on your I-94, you will be admitted on your I-94 to no later than your passport expiration date. If you wish to stay longer than that, either 1) an extension of stay must be applied for (the exact process depends on your status), or 2) you would have to leave and re-enter the US on a new passport (you would not need to get a new visa on the new passport, since a valid US visa in an expired passport can be used in combination with a valid passport from the same country).

This is as far as the US government is concerned. It is possible that the airline and/or originating country may have stricter requirements for passport validity.